# HERE Maps JS API implement through LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, api

*If I add this code **in normal text** file & save it as HTML, then at opening this in Chrome, it displays HERE Maps according to the text passed in below code.*

*If I add this code **in LWC** & try saving it, I get error like - Forbidden tags used..!!*

**I want to know how can I include this code in LWC & render Map**

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Simple HERE Map</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
   <style>
      html, body { border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="map"></div>
   <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
   <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
   <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
   <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
   <script>
      const platform = new H.service.Platform({ apikey: '*****************************' });
      const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
      const map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
         defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, 
         {
         center: { lat: '' , lng: '' },
         zoom: 3,
         pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
      });
      window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());
      const behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
      const ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

      //Begin geocoding
      const searchText = 'Pune';
      const geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService();
      geocoder.geocode({ searchText }, result => {
         const location = result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition;
         const { Latitude : lat, Longitude: lng } = location;
         const marker = new H.map.Marker({ lat, lng });
         map.addObject(marker);
      });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Show us the LWC code if possible, but just **FYI** LWC is template based, where `<script>`, `<html>` , `<head>` tags does not make sense. [Check here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc)

If you still want this same code in LWC then you can do this workaround.

Create a VF page, dump your code there, and host the VFPage as an iframe in LWC.

LWC:

```
<template>
    <iframe src="/apex/HelloWord" height=100% width=100%></iframe>
</template>
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page>
    <head>
        <title>Simple HERE Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css"/>
        <style>
            html, body {
                border: 0;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #map {
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100vw;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
    <script>
        const platform = new H.service.Platform({apikey: '*****************************'});
        const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
        const map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
            {
                center: {lat: '', lng: ''},
                zoom: 3,
                pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
            });
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());
        const behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
        const ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

        //Begin geocoding
        const searchText = 'Pune';
        const geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService();
        geocoder.geocode({searchText}, result => {
            const location = result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition;
            const {Latitude: lat, Longitude: lng} = location;
            const marker = new H.map.Marker({lat, lng});
            map.addObject(marker);
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I have completely implemented what I wanted to ...Thank you for suggesting. I have posted here what I have implemented - https://www.linkedin.com/posts/mohit-kulkarni-667119a4_saleforce-heretechnologies-api-activity-6738459269491933184-7Eua